# Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation

Tags: packages, warnings

I have the following code for my `main.tex` file and it gives the error message "Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation."

But I did not use the caption or subcaption package in my code. Can anybody tell me what is the problem? below is the code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\include{macro.tex}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
        
\begin{document}
    \title{Some title\\
        \thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
    }
    
    
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{abstract}
        Some abstracts
    \end{abstract}
    \begin{IEEEkeywords}
        some keywords
    \end{IEEEkeywords}
    
    \input{1. introduction}
    \input{2. related works}
    \input{3. preliminaries}
    \input{4. problem formulation}
    \input{5. solution approach}
    \input{6. experiments}
    \input{7. conclusion}
    \input{8. acknowledgments}
    
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{references}
    
    \input{tables and figures}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have not shown an example of the problem that anyone can use to see the issue and help. I would guess you are loading `caption`  in `macro.tex` but you have not shown it.

Comment: don't use \include in the preamble, use \input or \usepackage to load your macros.

Comment: Try commenting out all the \include and \input commands until the warning goes away. That should narrow down the search.

Comment: No my macro does not have caption. I checked myself. It is not loaded in any of the input files also. I checked all of them!